# How do you dynamically allocate memory in Mac OS X assembly?

Tags: macos, assembly, memory-management, sbrk

I would like to dynamically allocate memory from an assembly
program that does not link against the standard C library.
Since brk(2) and sbrk(2) are unavailable on Mac OS X (10.6.2),
what are the alternatives?

(I'm guessing that it involves a Mach call, but there seems to
be little documentation around that)

Comment: Why don't you want to link against the C library?

Answer (score 2):

Probably the easiest thing to do is look at the [Darwin sources](http://www.opensource.apple.com/release/mac-os-x-1062/) and see how malloc works internally.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like malloc calls mmap, which calls __mmap, which looks like it's just a syscall